# Dealing with interaction effects between fractional variables ... Does it matter that they're fractional?

Tags: regression, interaction, feature-selection, feature-scaling

I have a number of variables, $X_1, X_2, ...$  which vary between 0 and 1. These are measures representing metrics in a large organization -- e.g: *LeadershipScore* on a scale of 0 to 1, *ResponsibilityScore* on a scale of 0 to 1 etc. The DV is whether an employee got a promotion in the last 5 years, a binary response variable.

I am building two types of models:

- Random Forest Model: Goal is prediction
- Logistic Regression: Goal is explanation

**Maybe I am overthinking this but does it matter that the variables are fractional?** When I compute interactions -- like ResponsibilityScore * LeadershipScore I get very small numbers.

Comment: The size of the actual covariate doesn't matter provided your statistical analyzer uses floating point arithmetic; case in point if you regress y on x versus y on x/100,000 the results are in a sense equivalent: same r2, same yhats, betas proportional up to 100,000. With 0-1 scores, the regression coefficients can be huge, because their effect is interpreted as a 1-unit difference, i.e. worst-to-best. For that, you might just scale these scores by 10 or 100.

Comment: If you had parameterized your scores as between 0 and 100 instead, you'd be getting numbers concerning for how big they are :) Thankfully good regression algorithms in general don't mind either way